# Regex to ignore text between square brackets except strings between quotes

Tags: regex, quotes

I have such input:

```
[vc_custom_heading text="iWRITER for Box" ..... ]
```

and I have regex which captures everything between square brackets which makes possible to ignore everything between square brackets.

However, it is too much since I would like to exclude from capturing the text between quotes: `iWRITER for Box`

To make things clearer. Here is the screenshot: https://app.box.com/s/f2cj7tzrdqkjoocj3my6yo2w7nl4hcta

I need regex to capture everything in yellow.

Comment: Please clearly show us the starting text along with what you want to capture from it.

Comment: Programming language?

Comment: I need to capture everything except the text: iWRITER for Box

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want to do here.. so do you want to capture the text between the quotes or do you want to exclude it? You've mentioned doing both

Comment: ok, let me explain once again. I have a file with strings like that and software which allows me by regex to export what I want only. From the string [vc_custom_heading text="iWRITER for Box" ..... ] I would like to extract only iWRITER for Box. Is it clear now?

Comment: @WojciechMocek your comment is more clear than your question. Would you please edit your question so it is clear? Your comment says you want to match `iWRITER for Box`, but your question says you want to exclude from capturing that, which are opposites,

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your regex: `\"[^.]+\"`

Comment: This will also capture the quotes themselves. `\"(.*?)\"` would be the alternative

Comment: yes this works but I forgot to mention that I also need to extract everyting outside square brackets.

Comment: he said that he wanted to exclude everything between quotes

Answer (score 0):

To match only quoted text that is inside square brackets:

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?="[^\]]*\])
```